# cypress how to assert after page load result same as selected

Tags: cypress

i have script to select 2 button, 1st Yes, 2nd No.
Then click the Save button and reload page.
I want to assert after load, the page selection is same as the action done before load.

is there quicker way to assert based on my script input?

so i don't have to script the assertion line by line again.

my action script:

```
cy.get('#B1_check-true').click();
cy.get('#B2_check-false').click();
cy.get('#save-btn').click();
cy.reload()
```

Comment: I just study cy.wrap, not sure if this is right command that I can use. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assert a radio or checkbox is checked you can use:

```
cy.get('#B2_check-true').should('be.checked');
```

Comment: Alright, then I need to write line by line. No quicker way.